# I get a warning when I try to run the recursion program with return keyword

Tags: c++, recursion

I was expecting `1 2 3` as output, but when I try to run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int x){
    if (x>0){
        return fun(x-1);
        cout<<x<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x=3;
    fun(x);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this warning:

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Why doesn't it return the value and call `fun(x-1)`?

But the below code works perfectly. I get `3 2 1` as output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int x){
    if (x>0){
        cout<<x<<endl;
        return fun(x-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x=3;
    fun(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all you have statements after the `return`, which will never be executed. Then if the condition `if (x > 0)` is false, what do you return then?

Comment: How do you expect to be able to execute a statement in a function ***after*** returning from the function, before the statement can possibly execute?

Comment: This would be a *great* time to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a function has `return`'ed, it can't execute any more code:

```
if (x>0){
    return fun(x-1);
    cout<<x<<endl; // <-- NEVER EXECUTED
}
```

The warning is because your function has a non-`void` return type, but is not `return`'ing any value when `x` is `<= 0`, thus causing *undefined behavior*.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int x){
    if (x>0){
        int ret = fun(x-1);
        cout << x << endl;
        return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    fun(3);
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/FfQqmA)